Centering a caption in Overleaf APA7 template
I looked at the existing solutions but none of them worked for me. I've tried switching from pdfLatex to XeLatex and LuaLatex, but no luck.
I am using the standard apa7 template on Overleaf. I have the following commands in the preamble:
\usepackage{booktabs}
\captionsetup{justification=centering}  

I have something like this:
\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
\captionsetup{justification=centering}
\caption{Distribution of tasks by difficulty and category.}
\begin{tabular}{lccc}
\toprule
\textbf{Category}   & \textbf{Easy Tasks} & \textbf{Moderate Tasks} & \textbf{Hard Tasks} \\ \midrule
Math Problems       & 3                   & 5                       & 2                   \\
Memory Games        & 2                   & 4                       & 3                   \\
Logic Puzzles       & 1                   & 6                       & 5                   \\
Word Challenges     & 4                   & 2                       & 1                   \\ \midrule
\textbf{Total}      & \textbf{10}         & \textbf{17}             & \textbf{11}         \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\label{tab:task-distribution}
\end{table}




Please provide the MWE as in executable format, i.e., from \documentclass to \end{document}

It's true that the apa7 document class employs the caption package in order to impose the APA7 formatting guideliness for table and figure captions. But there's nothing in user manual of the apa7 package that indicates that it's acceptable to use \captionsetup directives to modify these formatting requirements. You're presumably using the apa7 class because you've been instructed to do so. (If you're not required to use this class, why do so anyway?) Deviating from the formatting requirements, in a highly visible and immediately noticeable way no less, might be asking for trouble.

@Mico I think you're right. I double-checked at APA 7 does want to leave them as-is. Thanks for this.

You can try with:
\documentclass{apa7}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\captionsetup{justification=centering}  
\usepackage{threeparttable}%%added
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
\captionsetup{justification=centering}
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{Distribution of tasks by difficulty and category
Distribution of tasks by difficulty and category Distribution of tasks by difficulty and category.}
\begin{tabular}{lccc}
\toprule
\textbf{Category}   & \textbf{Easy Tasks} & \textbf{Moderate Tasks} & \textbf{Hard Tasks} \\ \midrule
Math Problems       & 3                   & 5                       & 2                   \\
Memory Games        & 2                   & 4                       & 3                   \\
Logic Puzzles       & 1                   & 6                       & 5                   \\
Word Challenges     & 4                   & 2                       & 1                   \\ \midrule
\textbf{Total}      & \textbf{10}         & \textbf{17}             & \textbf{11}         \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\label{tab:task-distribution}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}


